# PHP changing code to use POST stops it working

Tags: php, forms

I have a weird bug with my code. I mistakenly used "GET" within my pngfile.php when my form was post, however I didn't notice it because my code worked. That working code is below:

main.php

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $data = $_POST['name']; // the data from text input.
}
?>
...
<form action="/app.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input name="colour" type="radio" value="1">Red
<input name="colour" type="radio" value="2">Blue
<input name="colour" type="radio" value="3">Green
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
 <img src="pngfile.php?data=<?php print urlencode($data);?>">
```

pngfile.php

```
<?php
   require_once 'functions.php';  
   $textdata = urldecode($_GET['data']);
   process($textdata);
   exit;
?>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
/* Generate Image */
function process($textdata)
{
...
```

However, it was pointed out to me that I was mixing POST form with GET in my code, so I changed it to use POST in my pngfile.php as below:

pngfile.php

```
<?php
   require_once 'functions.php';  
   $textdata = urldecode($_POST['data']);
   process($textdata);
   exit;
?>
```

But now it doesn't work! So it seems fixing the bug actually stops it working. Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong here.

EDIT: I don't really mind if I use POST or GET, but as long as it is consistent. The only way I can seem to get this working is by mixing POST and GET which doesn't seem right.

Comment: `$_GET` data is coming always from an URI, only if you set the `<form>` method to `GET` then form-data is generated as URI parameter. But you can never send `$_POST` data with an plain URI. Change your logic.

Comment: Did it work before with GET?

Comment: `action="/app.php"` I'm a bit confused. *app.php* doesn't seem to be shown here?

Comment: Can you try adding print_r($_POST); right after the <?php in your pngfile.php. Let us know what you get.

Comment: `I mistakenly used "GET"` is wrong statment, you can only send GET Data with an URI.

Comment: *"However, it was pointed out to me that I was mixing POST form with GET in my code, so I changed it to use POST"* - it seems to me that in this case, changing everything to GET would make more sense.

Comment: Where is the app.php file that the form is pointing to?

Comment: Do make it clear: That use of POST or GET in your `<form>` has nothing to do with the URI parameter in the `<img>` tag. The image is loaded when the form is not yet posted.

Comment: And as note: If no form is posted, your image URI looks like `pngfile.php?data=` always. The logic isnt good at all.

Comment: @domdom I'm happy to change it to get

Comment: @Zorgarath it worked when form was post and pngfile was get

Comment: This `abc.php?foo=bar` fills `$_GET` like `['foo'=>'bar']`, only a form can fill `$_POST` after submitting a form. But a form can use the method `get` so all form data will be URI parameter `abc.php?foo=bar`. By the way `$_REQUEST` is alway generated by php and holds all key:values from GET,POST,COOKIE merged together

Answer (score 1):

call off pngfile.php is in this line and it uses GET not POST  `<img src="pngfile.php?data=<?php print urlencode($data);?>">`

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="/app.php" method="post">
```

should be:

```
<form action="/main.php" method="post">
```

Comment: Thank you for this, unfortunately this was more a typo of my writing up my question but I will upvote you for the help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your main.php is sending data to pngfile.php via GET, but you changed the file to receive via POST.

`<img src="pngfile.php?data={...}">`

Is your problem because sending the data through the uri is a GET request, thus in pngfile.php POST won't be able to access that data.

EDIT:

In this particular case it's ok to mix GET and POST, and since you are only submitting a text name through the form for pngfile.php, I would say it would be perfectly ok to have pngfile.php keep using GET.

Answer (score -1):

Try with $_REQUEST, It will print either method is GET or POST. Also print the entire array like print_r($_REQUEST), may it will help.

Comment: I feel this answer will be downvoted by someone as you should always know what you are expecting. (Too late lol.) If I was really lazy, I would do just that.